# Can I run a C# WF App if I only have .NET 4.6?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to create a C# application to run during a Windows build using WinPE that only has .NET 4.6. 
Does this have the capacity to run a C# application utilizing the following:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

I know this should have been easy to find, but I couldn't find a list of the specific assemblies in .NET 4.6.

Comment: Sure, with a few well document exceptions .NET is backwards compatible. Stuff doesn't break with new versions.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what a document exception in .NET would be?

Comment: Just so no .NET nerds pointed out [closing over a foreach loop changed](https://davefancher.com/2012/11/03/c-5-0-breaking-changes/). Doesn't affect you, and it's the exception not the rule.

Comment: Did you read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes I did, it was just confusing to me because I am pretty new to C#. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the .NET Framework is backwards compatible

Please see this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939(v=vs.110).aspx

Excerpt from that page:

> The .NET Framework 4.5 and its point releases (4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, and 4.6.2) are backward-compatible with apps that were built with earlier versions of the .NET Framework. In other words, apps and components built with previous versions will work without modification on the .NET Framework 4.5. However, by default, apps run on the version of the common language runtime for which they were developed, so you may have to provide a configuration file to enable your app to run on the .NET Framework 4.5.